# Sorting the dataset on the basis of more than one columns

Tags: sorting, apache-spark

I have a sample dataset as below.

```
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Col1   |  Col2  | NumCol1 | NumCol2 | NumCol3 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 1 | Value2 |       6 |       2 |       9 |
| Value 3 | Value4 |       8 |       3 |      12 |
| Value 5 | Value6 |       1 |      11 |       8 |
| Value 7 | Value8 |       4 |      10 |       5 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need to Sort this dataset based on the values of Column(NumCol1,NumCol2,NumCol3) i.e If I have to sort this dataset as ascending order I need to get below result.

```
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Col1   |  Col2  | NumCol1 | NumCol2 | NumCol3 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 5 | Value6 |       1 |      11 |       8 |
| Value 1 | Value2 |       6 |       2 |       9 |
| Value 3 | Value4 |       8 |       3 |      12 |
| Value 7 | Value8 |       4 |      10 |       5 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

row with `Value 5  Value6 1 11 8` came first as it has lowest **1** similarly it folows.

If in descending order, result would be:

```
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Col1   |  Col2  | NumCol1 | NumCol2 | NumCol3 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 3 | Value4 |       8 |       3 |      12 |
| Value 5 | Value6 |       1 |      11 |       8 |
| Value 7 | Value8 |       4 |      10 |       5 |
| Value 1 | Value2 |       6 |       2 |       9 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is it possible to do this spark? How will be able to achieve the same?

Comment: In descending. Of 3 Numcolums whichever has highest data will come first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `least` and `greatest` to calculate the minimum and maximum among the three columns and then order by it. In **pyspark**:

*Ascending* by the least value:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.orderBy(f.least(f.col('NumCol1'), f.col('NumCol2'), f.col('NumCol3'))).show()
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|   Col1|  Col2|NumCol1|NumCol2|NumCol3|
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|Value 5|Value6|      1|     11|      8|
|Value 1|Value2|      6|      2|      9|
|Value 3|Value4|      8|      3|     12|
|Value 7|Value8|      4|     10|      5|
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

*Descending* by the greatest value:

```py
df.orderBy(f.greatest(f.col('NumCol1'), f.col('NumCol2'), f.col('NumCol3')).desc()).show()
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|   Col1|  Col2|NumCol1|NumCol2|NumCol3|
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|Value 3|Value4|      8|      3|     12|
|Value 5|Value6|      1|     11|      8|
|Value 7|Value8|      4|     10|      5|
|Value 1|Value2|      6|      2|      9|
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```